# Will unplugging 97 Dodge radio reset volume?

Tags: audio, dodge, ram

On my 97 Dodge Ram 1500, the radio volume knob is broken. Turning it either direction only *raises* the volume.

Now I accidently raised the volume too high, and have no way to lower it.

Will disconnecting the battery (or removing the radio fuse) reset the volume? This type of radio has a knob that does not stop when you get to the min or max volume. It can be turned forever in either direction.

[image: picture of stock radio]

Comment: The best I could tell you is to try it. What do you have to lose? Secondarly, I'd bet a used stock head unit would be cheap to replace in this ... that'd solve your problems completely. I'm thinking you'd have to disconnect the battery in the vehicle. I don't know if there's a security aspect to your head unit, though. I'd hate to see you pull the power only to figure out you don't have the security code for it.

Comment: yea I would take the battery then the radio out and replace the fuse